# Why javascript static variable not able to access ( using class name ) without creating minimum one instance?

Tags: javascript

I am creating one function like below

```
function calculation(){
    this.add=function(x,y){
        return x+y; 
    }   
    calculation.sub=function(x,y){
        return x-y; //static method
    };
    function mul(x,y){
        return x*y; //static method
    }
    calculation.mul=mul;
}
```

after declaration of this method, if call like this `calculation.mul(2,1)` I am getting an error like.

> *VM3676:1 Uncaught TypeError: calculation.mul is not a function
>           at :1:13*

But, `var _calc=new calculation();` after creation of instance, I am able to access the static method.

```
calculation.mul(2,1) if i try after this, i am getting value `2`.
```

Anyone, please clarify me. Thanks, advance.

Comment: You are assigning `mul` in the constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the code which assigns the `mul` property to the `calculation` object:

> ```
> calculation.mul=mul;
> ```

… is *inside* the `calculation` function. Therefore it only runs when you call the `calculation` function.

Move it outside if you don't want it to work that way.

```js
function calculation() {
  this.add = function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
  }
  calculation.sub = function(x, y) {
    return x - y; //static method
  };
}

function mul(x, y) {
  return x * y; //static method
}
calculation.mul = mul;

console.log(calculation.mul(2, 1))
```